# THashedStringList more performant alternative in finding items

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I found a performance bottleneck in an application i am maintaining in which a odd technique is used for localizing the user interface.

name value pairs are stored in a quite big `THashedStringList` and the bottleneck is given (profiler results) by all the calls to

```
THashedStringList.IndexOfName
```

and

```
THashedStringList.ValueFromIndex
```

Somehow I'd like to have a faster class that somehow can work with a similar signature (`indexOfName` and `ValueFromIndex`) so i can achieve a performance improvement without rewriting this odd-but-working localization mechanism. This code was written originally with Delphi 2009 i think, but now I have Seattle.

Thanks.

Comment: The obvious thing to try is `TDictionary<string,string>`. Although I suspect that the only difference will be the hashing code. Probably `TDictionary` uses faster hashing code. Without some concrete details, example data, timings, expected performance levels, we can but guess. What you should do is spend the time to extract a [mcve] that demonstrates your issues. That will require effort on your part, but there will be a reward.

Comment: you are right, i will prepare an example.

Comment: This does not need any evidence - it is known that THashedStringList is crap if you have many items as it is just for faster lookup of a TMemIniFile which rarely has thousands of sections and values. It uses a hashmap with a fixed size of 256 buckets thus having tons of collisions and turning this quickly into an O(n)

Comment: 256 buckets! Nasty. I didn't dig that deep, hard to anticipate such ineptitude. So, yeah, try `TDictionary<K,V>` first.

Comment: `THashedStringList.Create()` takes has `Size` parameter that defaults to 256 buckets. So it may be much easier to check how many strings you have and set the size accordingly. _I assume the localisation `THashedStringList` doesn't change after initialisation? If it does, there's a much bigger problem... Every time the strings change, the entire table needs to be rehashed!_

Comment: @CraigYoung `THashedStringList` does not take bucket size anywhere. The size is passed to the `TStringHash.Create` with a default value of 256 which is thus hardcoded in `UpdateNameHash` `UpdateValueHash` - look into the code.

Comment: @StefanGlienke Ah yes, thanks; I missed that. Clearly a horrible design and tricky to spot some of the nuances.

Answer (score -2):

I can not post the code here (just the interface), because it's will be too big, but if you go on alcinoe (https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe) you have a set of TStringlist like compoment, especially one called TALHashedStringList that work exactly like THashedStringList but internally it's use TDictionnary (so now timetaken by TALHashedStringList.IndexOfName and TALHashedStringList.ValueFromIndex must be null)

```
  {----------------------------------}
  TALHashedStringList = class(TALStrings)
  private
    FNodeList: TObjectList<TALHashedStringListDictionaryNode>;
    FDictionary: TALObjectDictionary<ansiString, TALHashedStringListDictionaryNode>;
    FDuplicates: TDuplicates;
    FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnChanging: TNotifyEvent;
    FOwnsObject: Boolean;
    FCaseSensitive: boolean;
    procedure ExchangeItems(Index1, Index2: Integer);
    procedure QuickSort(L, R: Integer; SCompare: TALHashedStringListSortCompare);
    procedure SetCaseSensitive(const Value: Boolean);
    function GetCaseSensitive: Boolean;
    Function ExtractNameValue(const S: AnsiString; var Name, Value: AnsiString): Boolean;
    procedure SetDuplicates(const Value: TDuplicates);
    function CreateDictionary(ACapacity: integer; aCaseSensitive: boolean): TALObjectDictionary<ansiString, TALHashedStringListDictionaryNode>;
  protected
    function GetName(Index: Integer): AnsiString; override;
    function GetStrictName(Index: Integer): AnsiString; override; // [added from Tstrings]
    function GetValue(const Name: AnsiString): AnsiString; override;
    procedure SetValue(const Name, Value: AnsiString); override;
    function GetValueFromIndex(Index: Integer): AnsiString; override;
    procedure SetValueFromIndex(Index: Integer; const Value: AnsiString); override;
    procedure SetPersistentValue(const Name, Value: AnsiString); override; // [added from Tstrings]
    procedure SetPersistentValueFromIndex(Index: Integer; const Value: AnsiString); override; // [added from Tstrings]
    procedure Changed; virtual;
    procedure Changing; virtual;
    function Get(Index: Integer): AnsiString; override;
    function GetCount: Integer; override;
    function GetObject(Index: Integer): TObject; override;
    function GetTextStr: AnsiString; override;
    procedure Put(Index: Integer; const S: AnsiString); override;
    procedure PutObject(Index: Integer; AObject: TObject); override;
    procedure SetCapacity(NewCapacity: Integer); override;
    procedure SetUpdateState(Updating: Boolean); override;
    procedure InsertItem(Index: Integer; const Name, Value: AnsiString; AObject: TObject); overload; virtual;
    procedure InsertItem(Index: Integer; const S: AnsiString; AObject: TObject); overload; virtual;
    procedure AssignTo(Dest: TPersistent); override; //[added from Tstrings]
    procedure init(OwnsObjects: Boolean; ACapacity: Integer); virtual; //[added from TStringList]
  public
    constructor Create; overload; override;
    constructor Create(OwnsObjects: Boolean); reintroduce; overload;
    constructor Create(ACapacity: Integer); reintroduce; overload; //[added from Tstrings]
    constructor Create(OwnsObjects: Boolean; ACapacity: Integer); reintroduce; overload; //[added from Tstrings]
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Add(const S: AnsiString): Integer; override;
    function AddObject(const S: AnsiString; AObject: TObject): Integer; override;
    function AddNameValue(const Name, Value: AnsiString): Integer; override; // [added from Tstrings]
    function AddNameValueObject(const Name, Value: AnsiString; AObject: TObject): Integer; override; // [added from Tstrings]
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
    procedure Clear; override;
    procedure Delete(Index: Integer); override;
    function  ExtractObject(Index: Integer): TObject; overload; virtual;
    procedure Exchange(Index1, Index2: Integer); override;
    function IndexOf(const S: AnsiString): Integer; override;
    function IndexOfName(const Name: AnsiString): Integer; override; // [added from TStringList]
    procedure Insert(Index: Integer; const S: AnsiString); override;
    procedure InsertObject(Index: Integer; const S: AnsiString; AObject: TObject); override;
    procedure InsertNameValue(Index: Integer; const Name, Value: AnsiString); override; // [added from Tstrings]
    procedure InsertNameValueObject(Index: Integer; const Name, Value: AnsiString; AObject: TObject); override; // [added from Tstrings]
    procedure Move(CurIndex, NewIndex: Integer); override;
    procedure CustomSort(Compare: TALHashedStringListSortCompare); virtual;
    property Duplicates: TDuplicates read FDuplicates write SetDuplicates;
    property CaseSensitive: Boolean read GetCaseSensitive write SetCaseSensitive;
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
    property OnChanging: TNotifyEvent read FOnChanging write FOnChanging;
    property OwnsObjects: Boolean read FOwnsObject write FOwnsObject;
  end;
```

you can see the performance with this demo :
https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/demos/ALSortedListBenchmark/win32/ALSortedListBenchmark.exe

Comment: This is a very poor idea. Use a dictionary directly and stop trying to fit everything into TStrings derivatives and keep using this lame interface. Break free. Use a dictionary. Also, you failed to mention anything about performance.

Comment: Why poor idea? it's exactly what LaBracca is asking! he don't want to rebuild everything and instead want something with the same interface as THashedStringList in pair with performance! And sorry but using Tdictionary inside a Tstrings is a brillant idea, because you can not do in TDictionary everything you can do with TString (like ordering the items) and vice versa you can not do in Tstringlist what you can do with TDictionary (like fast as hell IndexOfName). so merging the both world to have the best of all it's very good. off course it's also depend of the need (if you need the 2 worlds)!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and about performance, i say it, timetaken of TALHashedStringList.IndexOfName will be null (it's like doing myarray[x], it's will be immediate)

Comment: Wrong on both counts in my view.

Comment: in you view maybe :) but this control answer perfectly the question without any compromise (it's not a sparadra). if in it's code he also do something like myList[i] := 'xxx' he will spend lot of time to replace all of this by tdictionary, wast of time and resource for nothing (in my view)

Comment: How does one quicksort a hashed list of anything, unless you create an array (or some other copy) out of it and sort and return that?

Comment: @rudy : Yes the idea is to have a very tiny array for the quicksort (FNodeList: TObjectList<TALHashedStringListDictionaryNode>;) so in this way you can order the item in the way you need (like you can do with TStringList) or insert them where you want. but thanks to the dictionary (FDictionary: TALObjectDictionary<ansiString, TALHashedStringListDictionaryNode>;) you can retrieve item by IndexOfName as fast as hell. The overhead is very little (just this array of pointer)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: so explain how to order the item in a way you want with a Tdictionary ? and how to insert an item at the position X ? i say you it's depend of the need, if you need a Tdictionary then use a Tdictionary, if you need to order the item then you need a tstringlist, if you need to order the item and a fast as hell IndexOfName then you need the TALHashedStringList  :)

Comment: He doesn't need to order the collection

Comment: FWIW, what is a sparadra? Did you mean the French word sparadrap, or English band-aid?

Comment: *The overhead is very little* You are in fact maintaining two lists: the `TObjectList<somenodetype>` and the `TDictionary<,>`. That's quite some overhead.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you don't know he say " achieve a performance improvement without rewriting this odd-but-working localization mechanism" and he also say he need "THashedStringList.ValueFromIndex"

Comment: @RudyVelthuis i was thinking sparadrap was also an english word :( yea i mean somethink like plaster or band-aid

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: yes i maintain 2 lists, but by overhead i mean the cost in resources and memory, it's can be neglect

Comment: No, that's just how you look things up in that dire class. A dictionary is all that is needed. The class is an abomination, a ball and chain.

Comment: Two lists (a dictionary is some kind of list too, with buckets that are lists too) is *at least* twice the number of resources, AFAICT. FWIW, he says he needs ValueFromIndex, not that he wants a THashedStringList. Actually, he seems to want a plug-in replacement.

Comment: @rudy please say this also to emb when they decide to move everything to 16 bit string ;) listen them this cost of memory was neglect (unicode use 2x more memory then 8 bit string) ;) ;) ... and please explain me how to do ValueFromIndex with a TDictionary ! me as i understand he don't want to redo the code from scratch ;) ;)